# Does my laptop support QHD external monitor?

Tags: laptop, monitors, compatibility

I have an asus laptop UX430 two years now, and I am very pleased. Now I would like to buy a new external monitor to connect it to my laptop.

I use my machine as a web development enviroment, programming, casual office tasks, light video editing etc.

I never had a 27" QHD, but I am afraid of buying one cause I don't know if my laptop supports it properly, and doesn't downgrade it to FHD or running QHD on 30 fps only.

I also have micro hdmi port so I will need to buy an adapter or hdmi cord.

I am concerned about my gpu, cpu, micro hdmi version, not able to run a monitor with QHD and 75hz. What do you say about it, could my UX430 support QHD on at least 75hz?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely.  If your computer has the MX150 GPU, then definitely.  On a [Tomsguide forum post](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/can-the-mx150-4gb-vram-run-4k.432725/), people are running 4k monitors with the same GPU, so yours should handle QHD just fine.  Do you have a friend with a 4k TV you could test this with?  That would be the best, and cheapest, way to find out.

Comment: Or a QHD screen, that would also work